# How to add label to a 'copy shadow' of an object?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following MWE which produces a stack of 4 squares with the top one marked by '0' label. What I want is to add labels '1', '2' and '3' to corresponding squares behind the top one.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node[
    minimum width = 3cm,
    minimum height = 3cm,
    draw, fill = white,
    copy shadow = {shadow xshift = 3ex, shadow yshift = -3ex},
    copy shadow = {shadow xshift = 2ex, shadow yshift = -2ex},
    copy shadow = {shadow xshift = 1ex, shadow yshift = -1ex}
  ] (Block) {};

  \node[inner sep = 2pt, below left] at (Block.north east) {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a loop here and labels so that you don’t have to place those manually.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false,border=40pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{
  copy shadow label/.style={
    at={(\myCopyshadownode.north east)},
    anchor=north east,
    inner sep=+2pt},
  labeled copy shadow xshift/.initial=1em,
  labeled copy shadow yshift/.initial=-1em,
  labeled copy shadow/.style={
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{\let\myCopyshadownode\tikzlastnode}
      node[copy shadow label/.try] {0}
    },
    @labeled copy shadow/.list={#1,...,1}},
  @labeled copy shadow/.style={
    copy shadow={
      shadow xshift={#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled copy shadow xshift}},
      shadow yshift={#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled copy shadow yshift}}},
    append after command={
      node[copy shadow label/.try,
           xshift=#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled copy shadow xshift},
           yshift=#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled copy shadow yshift}] {#1}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [
    minimum size=+3cm, draw, fill=white,
    labeled copy shadow=3] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Outside of tikz, they can be stacked in a nested fashion.  You can set the horizontal and vertical shifts.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\mypic#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    minimum width = 3cm,
    minimum height = 3cm,
    draw, fill = white,
  ] (Block) {};

\node[inner sep = 2pt, below left] at (Block.north east) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\unskip}
\def\hgap{\hspace{1em}}  % YOU CAN ALTER THIS HORIZONTAL SHIFT
\setstackgap{L}{2ex}     % YOU CAN ALTER THIS VERTICAL SHIFT
\def\stackalignment{l}
\def\stacktype{L}
\stackon{\hgap\hgap\hgap\mypic{4}%
}{%
  \stackon{\hgap\hgap\mypic{3}%
  }{%
    \stackon{\hgap\mypic{2}%
   }{%
      \mypic{1}%
   }%
  }%
}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the vertical stackgap is set negative, the result (unsurprisingly) takes a different form:

[image]