# Overlay multiple boxes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Seriously, I have no idea where to start to draw this image. Especially, the overlaying boxes on top make me somehow clueless at this point...

I know, there are some amazing tikz-gurus in here, maybe could one please shed some light?

[image]

Thank you very much for all the helpful tips!

Cheers!
Martin

Comment: Section `69.3.2 Copy Shadows` of the pgfmanual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such things can be done with `copy shadow`, which supports up to two copies. If you want more than those, you could either write a new style for that (like `triple shadow`, say) or just copy the box with `foreach`. The first option has been worked out in [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128563/121799). However, in the present case, in which these are simple squares, the second option is arguably easier to implement.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{leftcol}{RGB}{68,98,96}
\definecolor{rightcol}{RGB}{39,61,73}
\begin{tikzpicture}[square/.style={rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum
height=1cm,draw=leftcol!80,thick,fill=white},font=\sffamily\bfseries]
  \node[square] (square1){};
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,3,4}
  {\node[anchor=north west,below right=2mm and 2mm of square\Y.north west,square] (square\X){};}
  \node[square,below=1.5cm of square1] (square5){};
  \node[fit=(square1)(square4)](fit1){};
  \draw[decorate,decoration=brace,white,very thick] (fit1.north east) --
  (fit1.south east) node[midway,right,align=left] (Train) {Train \& Valitidate\\
  Models};
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace},white,very thick] (square5.south east) --
  (square5.south west) node[midway,below] (Test) {Test Score};
  \draw[thick,-latex,white] (Train) -- (Test.north east);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit=(square1) (Test) (Train),left color=leftcol,right color=rightcol,
    inner sep=3mm]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]